# Python's json.dumps (or) loads in haskell-aeson?

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

In [Aeson library](https://github.com/bos/aeson/blob/master/examples/Simplest.hs#L7) meant for object serializing/deserializing, I see the functions, `FromJSON` & `ToJSON` declared as instances. The code is,

```
data Coord = Coord { x :: Double, y :: Double }
         deriving (Show)
instance ToJSON Coord where
toJSON (Coord xV yV) = object [ "x" .= xV,
                              "y" .= yV ]
```

My questions are,

- Why does the author create `ToJSON/FromJSON`  instances with just one method? Can't `toJSON`/`parseJSON` be written as a function on its own?
- In Python, one just does `json.loads/json.dumps` to handle any kind of object/json-string. Why does the haskell user need to write all these extra code for every object that he seralizes?
- For composite objects with multiple hierarchies like

`{"a":
    {"b":
        {
          "c":1
         }
    }
}`
, do we need to create multiple `data` and `instance` at each level?

Comment: I asked a very similar question and the answer is, no you don't need to make a type for every level of your return value. See the excellent answer I got here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28923006/isolate-a-single-value-from-a-nested-json-response-in-aeson/28927083

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Why does the author create `ToJSON`/`FromJSON` instances with just one method? Can't `toJSON`/`parseJSON` be written as a function on its own?

You misunderstand a lot of things, so let me clear this up a little. `ToJSON` and `FromJSON` aren't functions. These are *typeclasses*. Typeclasses are a way to write polymorphic code in Haskell.

Here I would explain a very simplified and incomplete definition of json serialization. First of all we declare a typeclass:

```
class ToJSON a where
    toJSON :: a -> String
```

This statement basically says: "If `a` is an instance of typeclass `ToJSON`, then we can use function `toJSON` to serialize `a` into a JSON string".

When a typeclass is defined, one can implement *instances* of it for a variety of simple types:

```
instance ToJSON String where
    toJSON s = s

instance ToJSON Int where
    toJSON n = show n

instance ToJSON Double where
    toJSON n = show n
```

After you defined these simple implementation, you can apply `toJSON` to values of either `String`, `Int` or `Double` and it would get dispatched to a right implementation:

```
toJSON "hello"         -----> "hello"
toJSON (5 :: Int)      -----> "5"
toJSON (5.5 :: Double) -----> "5.5"
```

To go further we need a way to encode JSON collections. Let's start with lists. We want to express that if there is a value `a` that can be serialized into JSON, then a list of such values can also be serialized into JSON.

```````````
--        ,-- value 'a' can be serialized into JSON    
--       ,--------,    
instance (ToJSON a) => ToJSON [a] where
--                     ``````````-- A list of such values can also be serialized    
    -- | Here is how serialization can be performed
    toJSON as = "[" ++ (intercalate ", " $ map toJSON as) ++ "]"
```````````

We serialize each value in the list, separate them with ", " and enclose in brackets. Note that recursive call to `toJSON` gets dispatched to the correct implementation.

Now we can use `toJSON` on lists:

```
toJSON [1,2,3,4] -----> "[1, 2, 3, 4]"
```

You can go further and try to implement the whole JSON syntax. Your next step here might be maps. I'll leave it as an exercise.

My point was to explain that when you write `instance ToJSON Coord ...` you simply provide a way to serialize `Coord` into JSON. And this gives you an ability to serialize lists of `Coords`, maps with `Coords` and many other things. This wouldn't be possible without typeclasses.

---

> In Python, one just does json.loads/json.dumps to handle any kind of object/json-string. Why does the haskell user need to write all these extra code for every object that he seralizes?

An important point is that Python's `json.loads` wouldn't deserialize json into your object. It would deserialize it into a built in structure that might be equivalent to your object. You can do the same thing in Haskell by using template haskell which would declare `ToJSON`/`FromJSON` instances for you. Alternatively you can just dump the JSON into a key value Map and operate on it.

However, writing that extra code (or automatically generating it) gives you a lot of benefits which can be summarized with words "type safety".

---

> For composite objects with multiple hierarchies like ..., do we need to create multiple data and instance at each level?

No you don't. In case of a structure that you linked the instances that would transform a number into such a structure or vice-versa would look approximately like this:

```
-- | Just a wrapper for the number which must be stored in a nested structure
newtype NestedStructure = NestedStructure Int

instance ToJSON NestedStructure where
    toJSON (NestedStructure n) =
        object ["a" .= object ["b" .= object ["c" .= n]]]

instance FromJSON NestedStructure where
    fromJSON (Object o) = NestedStructure <$> ((o .: "a") >>= (.: "b")
                                                          >>= (.: "c"))
    fromJSON _ = mzero
```

Comment: hi zudov, in the last code snippet of yours - FromJSON - what does `>>=` do? i know .: is to construct a key-value pair. but why do you use another operator `>>=` before `.:` operator?

Comment: `.:` doesn't construct key-value pair. It actually takes an object (key-value map) and a key, returning a `Parser a` where `a` is a type of whatever value is under the key. `>>=` is a monadic bind, and in this case it allows us to 'bind' multiple parsers in a chain, where each consequent parser is applied to result of the previous one. So that `(o .: "a") >>= (.: "b")` would extract a value under a key "a" (this value turns out to be an object) and would pass that value to `(.: "b")` (which would extract a value under the key "b". And so on.

Answer (score 0):

> In Python, one just does json.loads/json.dumps to handle any kind of
>   object/json-string. Why does the haskell user need to write all these
>   extra code for every object that he seralizes?

One way to avoid this is to use the [deriving](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/guest-posts/2014-12-15-deriving.html) mechanism in combination with [GHC.Generics](https://ocharles.org.uk/blog/guest-posts/2014-12-15-deriving.html).

The "deriving" mechanism automatically generates typeclass instances for you, avoiding boilerplate. For example:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveGeneric #-}

import GHC.Generics

data VDPServer = VDPServer 
    { vdpHost :: String
    , vdpPort :: Int
    , vdpLogin :: String
    , vdpPassword :: String
    , vdpDatabase :: String 
    }
    deriving Generic

instance FromJSON VDPServer

instance ToJSON VDPServer
```

This is descrived in the [Type Conversion](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.8.0.2/docs/Data-Aeson.html#g:11) section of the documentation.

You can customize how the instances are generated using the [Options](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.8.0.2/docs/Data-Aeson-Types.html#t:Options) type:

```
aesonOptions :: Options
aesonOptions = defaultOptions 
    { sumEncoding = ObjectWithSingleField 
    , fieldLabelModifier = tail
    , omitNothingFields = True
    }

instance FromJSON VDPServer where
    parseJSON = genericParseJSON aesonOptions

instance ToJSON VDPServer where
    toJSON = genericToJSON aesonOptions
```

Sometimes, when dealing with complex preexisting JSON schemas, this approach doesn't work so well and one has to fall back to manually defining the parser. But for simpler cases it avoids you a lot of boilerplate.

> do we need to create multiple data and instance at each level?

All of the record fields must have their own `FromJSON`/`ToJSON` instances. Many common types (tuples, lists, maps, strings...) already have such instances, see the instance list for [FromJSON](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.8.0.2/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:FromJSON) in the documentation. But if not, you'll have to define them (maybe using the `Generic` trick again).

> In Python, one just does json.loads/json.dumps to handle any kind of
>   object/json-string. Why does the haskell user need to write all these
>   extra code for every object that he seralizes?

The Haskell equivalent of deserializing a JSON file into a composite of maps, lists, and privitive types is to read a [Value](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/aeson-0.8.0.2/docs/Data-Aeson.html#t:Value) object. This way one doesn't have to define a new record.